# Delete session key when browser is refreshed ( Django )

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

How do I delete session when the browser is refreshed by the user? I do know, the following deletes the session key.

```
del request.session['session_key']
```

Edit: 
I am trying to propagate user entered value across multiple forms in different views, and for that I am using session variable. However, when the user manually refreshed the page, I want to clear the session keys.

Comment: Do you have any way to detect that the browser refeshs the website ?

Comment: I don't. I do know how to delete the session key, but I want to delete the key, when the page is refreshed.

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Django (I can think of) to know if a page has been refreshed or just starting a new session, page etc. You could do something with the request and Javascript.

If after a page has finished loading you want to just remove all sessions dependant where you want this to happen, look at `Signals` or just removing the sessions after the request has finished in your view.

Re: deleting all sessions...

`flush()` Deletes the current session data from the session and deletes the session cookie. The user will remain logged in. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush

If you just want to delete each session key (and keep the user logged in) then do:

```
for key in request.session.keys():
    del request.session[key]
```

This deletes each session in `request.session`.